# How to enable Mercurial extensions (such as mq)?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue, mercurial-extension

I have installed Mercurial from the Ubuntu package repository. However I don't know how to enable extensions (`q*` commands). How should I do that? The help shows that

```
enabled extensions:
style  (no help text available)
```

I want to enable mq and hgk.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Enable extensions in `hgrc`.

> #### extensions
>
> Mercurial has an extension mechanism for adding new features. To
>   enable an extension, create an entry for it in this section.
>
> If you know that the extension is already in Python's search path, you
>   can give the name of the module, followed by `=`, with nothing after the
>   `=`.
>
> Otherwise, give a name that you choose, followed by `=`, followed by the
>   path to the `.py` file (including the file name extension) that
>   defines the extension.
>
> ...
>
> Example for `~/.hgrc`:
>
> ```
> [extensions]
> # (the mq extension will get loaded from Mercurial's path)
> mq =
> # (this extension will get loaded from the file specified)
> myfeature = ~/.hgext/myfeature.py
> ```

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#extensions

Answer (score 8):

You can also enable an extension without editing the hgrc, if you want to do it one off. [[Source]](http://cerebralmanifest.com/enable-hg-extensions-for-one-command/)

```
hg --config extensions.histedit= --help
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of both extensions shows how to enable them : [MQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#Configuration), [Hgk](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgkExtension).

The usual way to enable an extension is to add a line to your `.hgrc` (or `Mercurial.ini` on some Windows system). It is explained in the [hgrc documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#extensions).

In your following case, add this to your configuration file :

```
[extensions]
mq =
hgk=
```

You can put it in your global configuration file or the repository one, depending if you want to have the extensions activated in every repository or just a specific one.

Answer (score 3):

The output of `hg help extensions` starts with

> **Using additional features**
>
> Mercurial has the ability to add new features through the use of
>   extensions. Extensions may add new commands, add options to existing
>   commands, change the default behavior of commands, or implement hooks.
>
> Extensions are not loaded by default for a variety of reasons: they can
>   increase startup overhead; they may be meant for advanced usage only; they
>   may provide potentially dangerous abilities (such as letting you destroy
>   or modify history); they might not be ready for prime time; or they may
>   alter some usual behaviors of stock Mercurial. It is thus up to the user
>   to activate extensions as needed.
>
> To enable the "foo" extension, either shipped with Mercurial or in the
>   Python search path, create an entry for it in your configuration file,
>   like this:
>
> ```
> [extensions]
> foo =
> ```
>
> You may also specify the full path to an extension:
>
> ```
> [extensions]
> myfeature = ~/.hgext/myfeature.py
> ```

So just add

```
[extensions]
mq =
```

to enable the MQ extension.

Comment: I am using Mac, how to add mq= in the terminal screen? How to save/ exit?